# Как создать виртуальный диск в c# для синхронизации с облаком

Tags: c#, .net, синхронизация, облачное-хранилище

Есть отличная програмка диск O:, она создает виртуальный диск в винде, который синхронизирован с облаком, но там нет поддержки общих папок в гугл диске. Вот я хотел бы эту проблему решить, уже более менее разобрался в апи гугл диска, а вот как теперь эти файлы в виртуальном диске отобразить и реализовать функциональность передачи файлов?

Comment: В `c#` — никак. `WinAPI/PInvoke` — пожалуйста.